# JavaScript Countdown Timer Code [JS]

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown

I'm currently trying to get a countdown timer working but, I don't know JavaScript at all.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var $timer = $("#timer");

    function update() {
        var myTime = $timer.html();
        var ss = myTime.split(":");
        var dt = new Date();
        dt.setHours(0);
        dt.setMinutes(ss[0]);
        dt.setSeconds(ss[1]);

        var dt2 = new Date(dt.valueOf() - 1000);
        var temp = dt2.toTimeString().split(" ");
        var ts = temp[0].split(":");

        $timer.html(ts[1]+":"+ts[2]);
        setTimeout(update, 1000);
    }

    setTimeout(update, 1000);
});
</script>
```

But I've stumbled upon a problem. So I want it to stop on 00:00, but it continues going.
Also at 2 minutes left and no time remaining I want it to execute some code.

At no time remaining (00:00) I want it to simply redirect to a page and at 2 minutes remaining I want it to run some custom code (Which I have).

But I have no idea on how to make it run at a time and make it stop at a time.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
    $timer.html(ts[1]+":"+ts[2]);

         if((ts[1]==="02") &&(ts[2]==="00")){
              //custom code at 02:00
           }

         if((ts[1]==="00") &&(ts[2]==="00")){
              //Make the redirect
          }
         else{ 
              setTimeout(update, 1000);
             }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sERaL/1/)

Comment: Hmmm, for some reason. Although it works on JSFiddle, it's not working on my site :/

Comment: What errors do you get? Maybe post a fiddle with code from your site?

Comment: I'm an idiot. I had it in the wrong location. Sorry about that. It work perfectly. Thanks a million!

Comment: Also just one last question. For some reason the countdown is a line down so it doesn't show it on the line I want.

Comment: This is a CSS problem. I need to see your CSS to figure out what is wrong. If i guess try play with margin or padding of the element

Comment: I want to add this to the 2 minute remaining section, how do I modify it to run in that section? http://hastebin.com/gewukoluki.sm

Comment: http://pastebin.com/e1HxBa4r That should work. I know that it won't work because of the onClick but what should it be changed to?

Answer (score 0):

The inner function should be a sybling of the anonymous function. Right now `update()`, can't be called because you are using `setTimeout()` -> update() should be on the same level as your anonymous function.